# Text on the right hand side column overflows to adjacent column

Tags: two-column, polyglossia, eledmac, eledpar

I need to have a parallel column layout with Hebrew on the left and Greek on the right. Within the test I need to add footnotes. However adding footnotes causes a disruption on the column layout causing the right hand side column to overflow into the left hand side column.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{greek, hebrew}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{SBL Greek}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{SBL Hebrew}
\begin{document}
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
    \begin{hebrew}
    \pstart

בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃

    \pend
    \pstart

וְהָאָ֗רֶץ הָיְתָ֥ה תֹ֨הוּ֙ וָבֹ֔הוּ וְחֹ֖שֶׁךְ עַל־פְּנֵ֣י תְה֑וֹם וְר֣וּחַ אֱלֹהִ֔ים מְרַחֶ֖פֶת עַל־פְּנֵ֥י הַמָּֽיִם׃

    \pend
  \end{hebrew}
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\begin{greek}
\pstart
Ἐν ἀρχῇ\footnote{This is a normal footnote} ἐποίησεν ὁ             θεὸς τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν. Ἐν  ἀρχῇ ἐποίησεν ὁ θεὸς  τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν. Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἐποίησεν ὁ θεὸς τὸν
        οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν. Ἐν ἀρχῇ             ἐποίησεν ὁ θεὸς τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν. Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἐποίησεν ὁ θεὸς τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν.
\pend
\pstart
Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἐποίησεν ὁ             θεὸς τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν. Ἐν  ἀρχῇ ἐποίησεν ὁ θεὸς  τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν. Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἐποίησεν ὁ θεὸς τὸν
        οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν. Ἐν ἀρχῇ             ἐποίησεν ὁ θεὸς τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν. Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἐποίησεν ὁ θεὸς τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν.
\pend
\end{greek}
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns
\end{document}
```

This is what happens:

[image: Column overflows when footnote is added]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the "familiar footnote" of reledmac.

So not using `\footnote` but `\footnoteA`.

But there is indeed a bug, normally `\footnote` should works well in parallel columns. So open an issue on ledmac github page (I won't have time to do it until many days).